# No carga boostrap cuando levanto el servidor en JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, vscode

Tengo el siguiente problema con este código que tomé de ejemplo de la página de Boostrap.
Cuando abro el archivo index.html me muestra los estilos correctamente, pero cuando lo pego en mi VSCode para hacerle adaptarlo a mi proyecto ya no cargan los estilos. El código es exactamente el mismo. Les dejo las imágenes desde el index.html y desde el servidor

[image: Asi se ve cuando abro el index.html]

[image: Asi se ve cuando levanto el servidor]

Les dejo el código

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.104.2">
    <title>Cover Template · Bootstrap v5.2</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/cover/">

<link href="../assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      
    </style>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="d-flex h-100 text-center text-bg-dark">
    
<div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Alejandro, cargas el estilo de bootstrap por medio de `href="../assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` si estas seguro de que tienes ese archivo en ese directorio correctamente en tu proyecto? Hay algun error en la consola tipo 404 que indica que no encuentra ese archivo?

Comment: En lugar de intentar cargar el bootstrap.min.css desde tu disco, que por lo que me parece no tienes ni descargado, hazlo desde un CDN y así te ahorras ese problema. Es decir, pon `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">` en lugar de lo que has puesto.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo como me dijiste, se acomodó un poco pero no termina de quedar igual, no me carga la fuente ni los hover de la NavBar

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el codigo, lo probe con mi vscode y me funciono ala perfeccion agregando el link de bootstrap por cdn y agregando la hoja de estilos cover.css y el estilo en head(un estilo extra) que se pone entre el head del html index, pongo el codigo

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */


/* Custom default button */
.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

body {
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.cover-container {
  max-width: 42em;
}


/*
 * Header
 */

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.104.2">
    <title>Cover Template · Bootstrap v5.2</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap -->   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- fin estilos bootstrap -->


    <style>
        .bd-placeholder-img {
          font-size: 1.125rem;
          text-anchor: middle;
          -webkit-user-select: none;
          -moz-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
        }
  
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
          .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
            font-size: 3.5rem;
          }
        }
  
        .b-example-divider {
          height: 3rem;
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
          border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
          border-width: 1px 0;
          box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        }
  
        .b-example-vr {
          flex-shrink: 0;
          width: 1.5rem;
          height: 100vh;
        }
  
        .bi {
          vertical-align: -.125em;
          fill: currentColor;
        }
  
        .nav-scroller {
          position: relative;
          z-index: 2;
          height: 2.75rem;
          overflow-y: hidden;
        }
  
        .nav-scroller .nav {
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
          padding-bottom: 1rem;
          margin-top: -1px;
          overflow-x: auto;
          text-align: center;
          white-space: nowrap;
          -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        }
      </style>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="d-flex h-100 text-center text-bg-dark">
    
    <div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
      <header class="mb-auto">
        <div>
          <h3 class="float-md-start mb-0">Cover</h3>
          <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center float-md-end">
            <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0 active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0" href="#">Contact</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
    
      <main class="px-3">
        <h1>Cover your page.</h1>
        <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
        <p class="lead">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary fw-bold border-white bg-white">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </main>
    
      <footer class="mt-auto text-white-50">
        <p>Cover template for <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/" class="text-white">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo" class="text-white">@mdo</a>.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    
    
        
      </body>
    
<div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

recuerda el otro archivo que debe ir alado de tu index.html es cover.css y le pones el codigo del que puse en el apartad, me queda asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta parte en especifico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

requieres una hoja de estilo en este caso el cover, es el que centra lo que te hacia falta